# Random android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-resources

For some time we have been receiving weird android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException exception from our production application (via Play store).

The error commonly appears while trying to access to string resources declared in `res/values`.

To give a concrete example, in our Application subclass, we load a string ressources in `onCreate()` method (so at any app launch).

The string resource actually exists in `res/values` and the production application works fine on all our test devices so it cannot comes from a wrong generation of the `R` file.

We guessed it came from the fact the the values weren't redefined in other values package (like values-hdpi or other packages) and copying the string values into all packages actually stopped the exceptions.

Still, according to the Android documentation, if no specific values are found, the values of the default package are taken by default so we don't understand why this error occurs.

We are thinking it might be custom roms that don't operate 'normally' so I wanted to know if other people had the same issues or anyone had other suggestions.

Comment: Yep, same thing. Our app works perfectly fine in all our testing on about two dozen physical devices, but we're getting occasional R$NFE's from the Play store for such things as our main screen layout xml.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the comment, I was thinking I was the only one having such issues. So far, the only 'solution' I found is to copy all string definition in each String Ressources directories. Do you have other 'fixes' ?

Comment: None so far. What's worse: the missing layout XML could conceivably be caused by an edge case in the resource loading system, but we also have a handful of cases of a ClassNotFoundException for our Application class. I can't feasibly explain that.

Comment: I have run into similar problems and it ended up being the name of the resource (id) that I had to change. Almost like I was using a reserved word or something for the id.

Comment: I know it's a bit of an old question, but here is more a support comment. You're not alone, I'm getting random reports from Google Play with the same resourceNotFoundException for this line `text_color_gray_text = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.comment_text);` (pretty simple uh!) being called during Application onCreate(). For sure it only happens in some bizarre bad custom ROMs or bad devices, but I wonder if this error have something to do with calling those resources on the Application context instead of the Activity context.

Comment: Thanks for the support, so far the only fix I found was to double all keys in all existent res directory. Keep me inform if you have other alternatives.

Comment: Having the same issue on Android 4.4.

Comment: Still facing this in 2017

Comment: Surprisingly! I am able to reproduce this on a test device but it only happens when I download build via Play Store and doesn't happen when I install release build(with proguard enabled) via Android Studio. I am getting this error for some other system defined resource though. Digging into R.java error is for `abc_tint_btn_checkable=0x7f0d0097`

Comment: It's weird that installing the release apk manually works but downloading it from the playstore doesn't. Did you keep the original apk you uploaded to the PlayStore ? If so does it also happenif you manually install this apk ?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many Android devices with different configurations. So when we don't keep resources specific to corresponding matching device configuration[drawable-hdpi,values-en,layout-land etc] then android system looks into default configurations for that resource[drawable,values & layout].

**So recommending to keep both default & configuration specific resources in respective locations.**